# My checkbox list is not filled with the correspondant value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have 2 arraylist filled on the java side : 
One with a full list of Nature : `allNature` and another one with the selected one on the java side `natures`. How can I check the `natures` in the full `allNatures` list ?

I've read in the doc that " if our features property contained some selected values in our form-backing bean, `th:field` would  have taken care of that and would have added a  checked="checked"  attribute to the corresponding input tags.".

But the `allNature` list contains some elements and they are not checked.

Before this evolution `natures` and `allNatures` were String elements and it used to work. Now that I change it in `Nature` element it doesn't work anymore. Here, it's different object references.

Here is my html code :

```
<div th:each="nature : ${allNature}" class="checkbox">
    <label > 
     <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{natures}" th:value="${nature}" class="checkboxNature" />
         <span th:text="${nature.nom}">...</span>
       <span th:text="${nature.routage.nomRoutage}" >...</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

and the relevant (to me) java code in my controller :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {
    @ModelAttribute("allNature")
    public List<Nature> getAllNatures(final Topologie topologie)
            throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("ModelAttribute to get all Nature for Cadre : {}",
                topologie.getCadre());
        return natureService.getNaturesByVersionCadre(topologie.getCadre(),
                topologie.getVersionCadre());
    }
```

and the object reference

```
public class Topologie {
    private List<Nature> natures = new ArrayList<Nature>();
```

In my controller just before displaying the template, this code confirms that 3 elements on 6 in the `allNature` list , must be checked :

```
for (Nature nat : natSelect) {
    LOGGER.info(" nature : {}, contains: {}", nat.getNom(),
            allNature.contains(nat));
}
```

Result :

```
2017-12-05 12:11:45.450  INFO 6984 --- [nio-8990-exec-3] f.cnamts.navigo.web.TopologieController  :  nature : hi_atmplm2a_out, contains: true
2017-12-05 12:11:45.450  INFO 6984 --- [nio-8990-exec-3] f.cnamts.navigo.web.TopologieController  :  nature : hi_lm2aconv_in, contains: true
2017-12-05 12:11:45.450  INFO 6984 --- [nio-8990-exec-3] f.cnamts.navigo.web.TopologieController  :  nature : hi_lm2asign_out, contains: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since Nature is a user define datatype, to make work using th:field you have to override equals method in bean to define equality while comparing objects.

Comment: thanks for the answer but here you compare a String with a Nature imo. And that's my problem I think : Before this evolution, `natures` and `allNatures` were just String elements. That's why it used to work. Here, it's different object references

Comment: If both objects are of same class holding same data,  instead of having entire nature object in natures list i suggest like it can be a list of strings which holds name of selected natures.

Comment: I have to iterate on `Nature Objects` because the text of my checklists is 2 elements : the nature' s name (nom) and the nature's "routage". If I iterate on nature's name, I wouldn't have the nature's routage. At least I don't see how

Comment: If there is any attribute in Nature class that can identify the nature object uniquely? use that to compare i.e., your natures should be a list of string to use that code i have added.

Comment: Yes the nature.nom is unique, as you've guessed given your answer. I've read in the doc that " if our features property contained some selected values in our form-backing bean,  th:field would  have taken care of that and would have added a  checked="checked"  attribute to the corresponding input tags.". I've added details in my question, showing that, on the java side, the list contains some element but they are not checked. I've also upadated my code.

Comment: I've also tried an adaptation of your answer : `th:checked="${#lists.contains(natures,nature)}"` but I've the exception : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot execute list contains: target is null` while loading

Comment: @jayjaypg22 since Nature is a user define data type to make work using th:field you make have to ovverride toequals method. to make sure how you define equality.

Comment: Thanks it works fine : no `th:checked` needed. You can add an answer like override equals and I will add you some points! Thanks for your perseverance!

Comment: Good to know that worked, i updated the answer accordingly.